# One or more Apex triggers lack test coverage. Add test coverage for the following

Tags: apex, unit-test, failing-tests

> Upload Failed One or more Apex triggers lack test coverage. Add test
>   coverage for the following triggers and upload again: EmployeeScheduleTrigger

I have covered pretty much more than 75% of the test coverage but when I try to create the package I got the above error message.

I have looked at the `EmployeeScheduleTrigger` code coverage and its covered 77% except that few lines of code where I'm calling methods.

so I wrote the test coverage for those missing coverage and I still see in the developer console code coverage is showing as not covered.

What in my code is doing that its not doing code coverage for the `EmployeeCreation` ? I have double checked `isEmployeeCreated` returns true;

as shown below

[image]

here is my code coverage I have written:

```
Id employeeId;  
string Template_Order = "New123";
string AssetId = "AS-001";
static testMethod void doQueryOnEmployee()
{
    EmployeeClass byEmployee = new EmployeeClass();
    Boolean isEmployeeCreated = byEmployee.created(123,322,233,444); //it returns true -- double checked

    if(isEmployeeCreated)
    { 
       EmployeeId =  byEmployee.EmployeeCreation(Template_Order, AssetId); 
    }     
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate that you have double checked the value however if a row is marked as red it generally means that your test code is not covering that. Regarding the code coverage error. Please make sure that you are adding the test classes, the one you have created and the other which was already covering 77%, in your package deployment/ change set.

Comment: Are you deploying both the trigger and your test class? It sounds like you may only be deploying the trigger.

Comment: Are you checking the coverage of an actual class, or of a test method class? The latter doesn't matter. If you expect `isEmployeeCreated` to always be true in the test case you should assert it. E.g. `System.assert(isEmployeeCreated, 'Some useful message if it fails');

Comment: Have you added the test file into the package before uploading? It is not auto-added

Comment: @DanielBallinger: yes I'm deploying both trigger and test class as well and i'm checking the actual class coverage NOT the test method method class

Comment: @AbuHamzah The test class looks odd to me. It appears to be replicating the method to be tested rather than calling it. Still, add some assertions to verify things are working as expected.